# Send scores to facebook graph api from android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to post score points using facebook graph api, from my android application

I create android app in facebook developers page. I set to Native Android App , and I set Mobile Web settings like on image below

[image]

In  android code I user this permissions for my app:

`String[] permissions =  {"publish_stream","publish_actions","user_games_activity","friends_games_activity"};`

After successful login on facebook, I try to post score points to facebook using this android code

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("score", "100");
    //params.putString("access_token", "token as constant");

    String response = "null";

    Utility.mFacebook.setAccessToken("token as constant");

    try {
        response = Utility.mFacebook.request("user_id/scores", params, "POST");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I receive this response:

`{"error":{"message":"(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.","type":"OAuthException","code":15}}`

I get same error if I use Graph API Explorer:

[image]

In  facebook settings ->Apps -> AppName -> Advanced->App Type is set to "Web" (I also try with Native/Desktop but I get same error)

Can anyone help me and tell me how to sent score from my android app to fb?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "(#15) This method must be called with an **app** access_token."

Looks like you tried with an user access token.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/ on how to get an app access token.